# Convert Hindi PDF to Excel

Tags: excel, pdf, ocr, converters, hindi

I have a pdf in Hindi which I want to convert to an excel table. I have tried most of the available ways online but got no success yet. Can someone please help me with it? Any help would be highly appreciated. TIA! :)

[Here is the file](http://mppwd.gov.in/Uploads/GradationList/89/GRADTIONAECIVIL1413.pdf)

Comment: You may need to adobe acrobat pro to convert it. Remember, scanned page will not successfully convert text data. In that case you may need some image to OCR conversion paid tool.

Comment: Do you get any success?
I'm also actively looking for the answer